# What does a move entail?

Tags: tiny-epic-zombies

The Tiny Epic Zombies manual for the game states that a human turn consists of

1. Each Turn, you *MUST move 3 times*.
   Each Move could potentially consist of the following actions:
   *A.* Kill 1 zombie
   *B.* Use Room's Ability AND/OR Interact with a Token
   *C.* Collect items
2. Search Current Store

So far we have been playing the game as each human player can take 3 turns, moving once and performing three of the actions above.

Totalling 12 actions per human players turn. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1A: Kill 1 Zombie:

> After moving into a Room, you may kill 1 Zombie. [...]

So 1A can be performed each time you enter a room.

1B: Use Room's Ability and/or Interact with a Token:

> After moving into a Room (and killing a Zombie if necessary), [...] you may then use Room abilities and/or interact with Tokens. [...]

So 1B can clearly be done in addition to 1A. There's no reason to believe 1C is any different, so all of 1A to 1C can be done each time you enter a room.

Since you have three moves, you shall be entering three rooms, and thus go through 1A to 1C three times.

Then, you search your current store

> After completing 3 Moves, the Human Player flips over the facedown
>   Search Card in front of them and places this card face up next to the
>   Store they are in. [...]

So, in the right conditions, you could perform 10 actions per turn (13 if you count "Use Room's Ability" and "Interact with a Token" separately). Keep in mind the some actions (1B and 1C) can only be taken if the store is devoid of zombies.

1. Move 1 Room

   1. Kill 1 Zombie
   2. Use Room's Ability and/or Interact with a Token
   3. Collect Items
2. Move 1 Room

   1. Kill 1 Zombie
   2. Use Room's Ability and/or Interact with a Token
   3. Collect Items
3. Move 1 Room

   1. Kill 1 Zombie
   2. Use Room's Ability and/or Interact with a Token
   3. Collect Items
4. Search Current Store